# 2 vertical divs and full-width page

Tags: html

Just tired up with the problem with 2 div aligning vertically. I tried horizontal scroll is appear in browsers, how to get rid of scroll?
I have this html:

```
<div id="responsive-admin-menu"></div>
<div id="content-wrapper"></div>
```

The css code is

```
#responsive-admin-menu {
    width: 200px;
    left:0px;
    background-color: #404040;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 500px;
}

#content-wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    overflow:auto;
    width:100%;
    margin-left: 200px;
    right:200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: What do you wanto to do exactly?

Comment: both divs must fit in full-width browser windows

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to create a two columns fluid layout, where you have your #responsive-admin-menu to the left and #content-wrapper to the right, and they fill the entire browser window.

In this case I suggest to define the width of both divs in percent and let them float one to the left and the other to the right:

```
#responsive-admin-menu {
  width: 30%;
  float:left;
}

#content-wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  float:right;
}
```

take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/guybrushthreepwood/UpT3Z/) where I edited your code.

Comment: I think, he want the menu with "width:200px".

Answer (score 0):

[My Codepen](http://codepen.io/ColoO/pen/GsKlm)

Use left/top/right/bottom for to give "anonymous" width and height.

Your CSS

```
#responsive-admin-menu {

    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color: #404040;
    min-height:500px;

}

#content-wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    overflow:auto;
    top:0px;
    left:200px;   
    right:0px;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: ColoO! Great! You make my day! Thank you very much!

Comment: if it's ok you can validate. bye.